# insert into a table with a definite "label"

Tags: postgresql, select, insert

I have a table already created and full of data, and I want add some more rows.
These row do appear perfectly if I do something like:

```
select  elem_1, elem_2, 'myTag' as source, count(*) as tally 
from origin_table group by elem_1, elem_2;
```

What I am basically doing is taking data from origin_table, and selecting by elem_1 and elem_2 I attach the label "myTag" to each of these couples. Since I might have duplicates, I also consider count(*) as tally, to know that I have, in the origin_table, more than one equal entry. This is a detail, which might be avoided.

Now, if I move on ad do something like:

```
insert in to destination_table 
select  elem_1, elem_2, 'myTag' as source, count(*) as tally 
from origin_table group by elem_1, elem_2;
```

postgres barks:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "myTag"
LINE 1: insert into destination_table select elem_1, elem_2, 'myTag' as sou...
```

which I do understand but I don't like since I don't know how to overcome it.

So, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you write it like `in to`, really? (Should be `INTO`).

Comment: It is highly recommended that you list the columns in the insert statement (`insert into destination_table (col1, col2, col3) ... `) to avoid problems. I wouldn't be surprised if that was the reason for your problem

Comment: @Anton: uhm. No, I write INTO, as everybody else, but sometimes I forget to type it correctly :)

Comment: @horse: will try right now. That's a good habit I should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a_horse_with_no_name's advice I casted the insert into as:

```
insert into destination_table (elem_1,elem_2,source,tally) select elem_1, elem_2, 'myTag' as source, count(*) as tally from origin_table group by elem_1, elem_2;
```

and it works beautifully.
I should really pick up the habit of telling postgres what I am inserting and where.

Thanks!

Comment: A little nitpicking: specifying the insert columns is not called "*casting*". Casting is when a value is changed to a different data type than the original one. E.g. a number as a string, a string as a date.